# How do I get Angular 4 @import styles in component to work?

Tags: angular, npm, sass

For my Angular 4.0.2 Universal App I have a component (BlogComponent) with:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'blog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['blog.component.scss']
})
```

Within the stylesheet, I have:

```
@import '../../styles';
```

File structure:

```
/src
    styles.scss
    /app
        /blog
            blog.component.scss
```

i.e. main stylesheet in root and component stylesheet in app/blog

When I run `npm start` I get:

```
Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: C:/Users/robba/Angular4/robbailey3/src/styles
    at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:370:19)
    at CompilerHost.loadResource (C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:243:85)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24640:107)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13297:45)
    at C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13426:53
    at Array.map (native)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets (C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13426:14)
    at C:\Users\robba\Angular4\robbailey3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13429:26
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
Compilation failed
```

However, the import statement works fine when I use `ng serve`.

How do I get the `@import` statement to work for `npm start` or `npm build`?

Comment: What have you written in Package.json under script ?

Comment: I have got:   "scripts": {
    "prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc",
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
  }

Comment: What if `styleUrls: ['./blog.component.scss']`?

Comment: npm start is firing `ts-node src/server.ts` command

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh my src/server.ts file has nothing about styles. Why would this affect the @import?

Comment: At a stab here I'd say that `prestart` is not required to signal completion before `start` is executed. IMHO I think what you're doing is bad practice. if you want a custom server for an API during development then I consider it a lot better to add proxy settings for the webpack-dev-server being used. Also I prefer to keep any such backend in a separate project structure and run from there.

Comment: Furthermore. If your custom server is picking up SASS files that have not been pre-processed ( as the error suggests ) then you are likely pointing to the wrong directory. Make sure you are picking up `index.html` from `/build` and not `/src`